# AWS MSK vs Confluent for hosting Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, aws-msk

In terms of investing for the most value, how does AWS MSK compare to Confluent when it comes to hosting an end to end Kafka event sourcing?

The main criteria to be used for comparing are:

1. Monitoring
2. Ease of deployment and configuring
3. Security

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used open-source, on-prem Cloudera, and MSK.  When comparing them together they have all had their quirks.

1. If you just base on the speed of provisioning a secure Kafka cluster. I think MSK would win hands down. Someone with Kafka, AWS Certificate Manager, and Terraform can get it all done very quickly. Though there are a few issues around Terraform TLS and  AWS CLI but there are workarounds.
2. If you are planning to use Kafka Connect then confluent makes lots of sense.
3. If you have Kafka developers who have experience in writing Kafka Connect sinks and source. Well, then you may not need a subscription-based model from confluent. Though you may not save a lot of money. Either spend in development or spend in subscription costs.
4. If you like serverless - MSK is quite good. However, there is no SSH access to the Kafka cluster. You cannot tune the JVM.
5. Monitoring is built out of the box for MSK via open monitoring via JMX metrics and prometheus. You also have CloudWatch as well. But open monitoring pretty much gives all the metrics you need. In open-source, you can easily deploy monitoring. Rather MSK is doing the same.
6. MSK provides security using either TLS or IAM. Though there are some issues around enabling IAM-based security for MSK using Terraform. 2 Way TLS Client authentication is quite easy to set up.
7. MSK also provides auto-scaling but again if you are planning to use Terraform there may be some interoperability issues.

I am sure folks here can add a lot more on confluent.

Comment: Kafka Connect works with any Kafka cluster, not only Confluent. Confluent Cloud is quick to provision, has monitoring/altering, almost same security protections, and proactive support

Comment: @amitdash - Can you please stopping changing the question. This question has gone from comparing various Kafka distributions to open Monitoring to Kadrop. Please log a separate question if the context is totally different from the original question. Apologies for this comment.

Comment: @floating_hammer it is rolled back to the original version now